# Why error An internal server error has occurred Error ID: 1065883952-6153 (1010177878) happens?

Tags: gack, salesforce-cdp, datacloud, cdp

When I try to go to ruleset in data cloud, and click New button, I receive several errors including

```
An internal server error has occurred Error ID: 1065883952-6153 (1010177878)
```

Also I can't select a data space from the dropdown list.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It is related to invalid data spaces.

We need to delete invalid data spaces or open a SF Support case.

Update from SF Support.

Since there is no UI for Data Space deletion, one has to use [Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/) or other API tool to query Data Space records using the SOQL query

```
SELECT Id, Name, Description, DataSpaceApiName  FROM DataSpace
```

then follow the links for the broken data space records and delete them using workbench.